# Actions with variable argument count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working with Unity networking, and I'm writing a method that calls another one over the network. Currently I have a bunch of methods that look like

```
void Call<A>(Action<A> method, A arg) {
    _networkView.RPC(method.Method.Name, RPCMode.Others, arg);
}

void Call<A,B>(Action<A,B> method, A arg1, B arg2) {
    _networkView.RPC(method.Method.Name, RPCMode.Others, arg1, arg2);
}
```

...
And so on

There are also variants to call it on a specific player and a system to make it work with Photon Cloud. So there are a whole lot of these methods, and it's getting very cluttered.

Now, I was wondering if it's possible to have an Action that can have any amount of arguments. So I can make something like:

```
void Call(Action method, params object[] args) {
    _networkView.RPC(method.Method.Name, RPCMode.Others, args);
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you just need to use `Delegate.DynamicInvoke()`: You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Actions with variable argument count

It is possible:

```
public delegate void ParamArrayAction<V>(params V[] variableArgs);
public delegate void ParamArrayAction<F, V>(F fixedArg, params V[] variableArgs);
public delegate void ParamArrayAction<F1, F2, V>(F1 fixedArg1, F2 fixedArg2, params V[] variableArgs);
public delegate void ParamArrayAction<F1, F2, F3, V>(F1 fixedArg1, F2 fixedArg2, F3 fixedArg3, params V[] variableArgs);
```

## Your problem

But it's not what you ask for. Actually, you are asking for some magic delegate type to which any method is assignable. As far as I know it's impossible.

This is quite strange (or, maybe, I don't understand something). As far as I understand, you have whole bunch of methods like this

```
void Call<A>(Action<A> method, A arg) {
    _networkView.RPC(method.Method.Name, RPCMode.Others, arg);
}

void Call<A, B>(Action<A, B> method, A arg1, B arg2) {
    _networkView.RPC(method.Method.Name, RPCMode.Others, arg1, arg2);
}

.....

void Call<A, B, C, D>(Action<A, B, C, D> method, A arg1, B arg2, C arg3, D arg4) {
    _networkView.RPC(method.Method.Name, RPCMode.Others, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}

.....
```

And then you use them like this:

```
[RPC]
void DoSomething(string someText, int someValue)
{
    // Bla-bla-bla
}

.....

void SomeRPCCallingMethod()
{
    // Bla-bla-bla
    Call(DoSomething, "Hello, World!", 42);
    // Bla-bla-bla
}
```

And I kinda like it. It adds compile time check for method params. Which is good. What I don't understand is:

> there are a whole lot of these methods

Why? I'm not familiar with Unity's RPC. But anyway, you can:

1. Create a separate class which will encapsulate `NetworkView` and `Call<>` methods.
2. Add `RPCMode` as a parameter to `Call<>` methods.

If you still want to do it, do it like this:

```
    void Call(string methodName, params object[] args) {
        _networkView.RPC(methodName, RPCMode.Others, args);
    }

Usage:

    [RPC]
    void DoSomething(string someText, int someValue)
    {
        // Bla-bla-bla
    }

    .....

    void SomeRPCCallingMethod()
    {
        // Bla-bla-bla
        Call("DoSomething", "Hello, World!", 42);
        // Bla-bla-bla
    }
```

Comment: You're right, this is exactly how I use them. I already encapulate my NetworkViews and the Call<> methods. Though I have a whole lot because I'm making it to work with both the default Unity Networking and the Photon Cloud. So for each number of arguments I have at least 3 methods: a normal Call<> (which checks whether you're using Photon or Unity and acts accordingly, I posted a simpler version in my question), then 2 more to Call something on a specific player (synce Unity uses NetworkPlayer and Photon uses PhotonPlayer.) So in total I have like 18 of these 'Call's who look almost identical.

Comment: Oh yes, it's indeed possible to directly give the name of the method as a string, though then it won't give an error when I forget to change the string when renaming the method. I like that I get compile-time errors now. So from your answer it seems it's not possible what I wanted to do. Having 18 almost identical methods isn't great, but not too bad either. I was just wondering if there's a better way. Still, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm... If you post all these methods, I'll try improve it. Maybe we can make it better, who knows

Comment: I posted my entire class, NetworkMonobehaviour, in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Kufsn5zK Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you have time to look at it? I was just adding functionality, so I have to change 18 methods, which is a pain. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Here is how I would approach this (at least this is what comes into my mind after thinking for 15 minutes): http://pastebin.com/aV8vwHkL

Comment: No problem, just though to remind you, and it worked :D That looks interesting, I'll have a better look at it later. But thanks a lot already!